# Modifier Line art doesn't work

Tags: grease-pencil, lineart

*Line Art* modifier doesn't work at all. I have an active camera in my scene. I tried to use different ways, but it didn't help.

My file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zgR3m5Bfxmz6qX-Venh4RUQeGdpOxsAD/view?usp=sharing